# C++ Load files from SQL database

Tags: c++, sql

I was wondering if it is possible to load binary files from a SQL database in C++ and use them just like normal files with fstream? If so, how?

Comment: Why would you? The format of any data file for any database will not be simple.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you are asking "I have a blob representing a file inside a SQL database, how can I use it" or "I have a binary SQL database file, and I want to do something with it" - if the latter, what is "something". As Joachim says, the format of an SQL database is far from trivial.

Comment: What DBMS do you use? Most of popular ones supports datatypes like 'blob', which you can use to store your data. On the client side, you can implement the class with behaviour you are want. And yes, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: What's blob? Can it show start byte, read size, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its possible,i have worked in c++ using sqlite3 database and stringstream.

[An Introduction To The SQLite C/C++ Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)

```
    sqlite3 *db; 
    sqlite3_open("dbfile.db", &db);
    sqlite3_stmt *companydetails;
    std::stringstream companystr;
    companystr << "select companyname,companydetails from company";
    sqlite3_prepare(db, companystr.str().c_str(), companystr.str().size(),&companydetails, NULL);
    sqlite3_step(companydetails);
```